# Reading environmental values in logstash config file

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Is there a way to read environmental values in logstash config file . I want to pass in an env value to write test cases for logstash config but I am not able to do so .
For ex I want to do the following in my logatsh config file

```
input {
 if [ $ENV_VALUE] = test {
    stdin{}
}else{
    Default config
}
}
filter {..}
output
{
 if [ $ENV_VALUE] = test {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}else{
   Default config
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [environment filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-environment.html)?

Comment: I have. but I do not want to add a new field/tag or a processing overhead to  to each event when I only want this switch to be active on input/output .

Comment: Well, you can't do conditional in input{} stanzas anyway.